# What are the steps I need to take to add a hyperlink to a web form

Tags: wffm

I see in the literature that I should be able to add a hyper link to at least the footer of a web form. I have attempted to set one up, but to no avail. Any support would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Sitecore Stack Exchange, Paul! What have you tried so far? Please add any applicable code snippets or screenshots that could help.

Comment: It would be helpful to see what you've tried so far, so we can direct you in the right direction!

Comment: I have tried using the HTML editor in Sitecore with no positive results...
<a name="the web" id="anchor_1547649409550">the web</a><a href="http://www.msn.com/" title="test" target="_blank">msn link</a>

Answer (score 1):

Good afternoon. You are able to directly write a "href" into the footer as shown in the image. `<a href="https://example.com">`

[image: Wffm footer hyperlink]